# Calling different procedures from a procedure based on input value

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to write a procedure which should be able to call different procedures based on the input value.

Example:

```
calling_proc(inp1, inp2, inp3)
begin
if inp3 = 1 then
   exec called_proc_1(inp1, inp2)
end;
if inp3 = 2 then
   exec called_proc_2(inp1, inp2)
end;
end;
```

The inputs for all the called procedures are same. Only the last input tells me which one to execute

Comment: And... what's your question?

Comment: Did you write some code? Please post it and tell us what's the issue with it

Comment: (Just in case it's the problem) `exec` is a SQL\*Plus command and is not required - in fact is invalid syntax - in PL/SQL, including anonymous blocks.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
create or replace procedure proc0(inp1 in number, inp2 in number, inp3 in number) is
begin
    case inp3
    when 1 then
        proc1(inp1, inp2);
    when 2 then
        proc2(inp1, inp2);
    .
    .
    .
    else ...
    end case;
end;
```